# React: Problem with adding new value to array

Tags: reactjs

I have a Posts component with posts array, including few posts just for example. Now I'm trying to add new post to my array and I want that post to be rendered with others. I dont have much experience with React, so I dont know how to add new element to an array. I tried to do it with "setPosts(...posts, newPost)", but it dont work, now all my posts disappeared after render.

```
const Posts = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
        {id: 1, title: 'First Post', content: 'First Post Content'},
        {id: 2, title: 'Second Post', content: 'Second Post Content'},
        {id: 3, title: 'Third Post', content: 'Third Post Content'}
    ]);

    const [newId, setNewId] = useState('');
    const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState('');
    const [newContent, setNewContent] = useState('');

    const handleIdChange = (e) => {
        setNewId(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleTitleChange = (e) => {
        setNewTitle(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleContentChange = (e) => {
        setNewContent(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newPost = {
            id: newId,
            title: newTitle,
            content: newContent
        }
        setPosts(...posts, newPost)
    }

    

    return <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='posts-form'>
        <label>
            New ID: <input type='text' onChange={handleIdChange} value={newId} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>
            New Title: <input type='text' onChange={handleTitleChange} value={newTitle} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>
            New Content: <input type='text' onChange={handleContentChange} value={newContent} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type='submit' value='Add' />
        </form>

        <PostsList posts={posts} />
    </div>

}

const PostsList = (props) => {
    return <div className='posts-list'>
        { props.posts.length > 0 ? props.posts.map(
            (post) => <div key={post.id} className='post'>
                <h1 className='post-title'>{post.id}. {post.title}</h1>
                <p className='post-content'>{post.content}</p>
            </div>
            ) : <h1 style={{color: 'gray', fontFamily: 'monospace'}}>No posts found!</h1> }
    </div>
}
```

I just want new post to be rendered with other posts, but it showing "No Posts found!" after submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets in your state like this and use spread operator on the posts state it will append the previous posts

```js
setPosts([...posts, newPost])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but it doesn't work when my PostsList is another component. I just copied my code from PostsList, put it at my Posts component and now it works. But it will be better, if it worked when my PostsList is another component. Maybe you know how I can fix that?

Comment: can you explain more on this?

Comment: If you want to update the array inside the PostsList component, then you can use the useEffect hook, pass the post prop in a dependency array of useEffect hook,so in this way whenever the new post is added then the post list will be updated throught useEffect

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation you're doing:

```
    setPosts(...posts, newPost)
```

doing so, you're passing 2 arguments to the `setPosts` function.
Whereas, `setPosts` functions expect you to pass a single argument representing your updated state which is the new array.

You can create a new array using spread operator `...` like this:

```
    [...posts, newPost]
```

The above statement spreads all the values from `posts` array, and add a new element `newPost` at the end of the new array created using `[]`.

So your implementation should be like this:

```
    setPosts([...posts, newPost])
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but it doesn't work when my PostsList is another component. I just copied my code from PostsList, put it at my Posts component and now it works. But it will be better, if it worked when my PostsList is another component. Maybe you know how I can fix that?

Comment: can you elaborate what problem do you face after making the changes suggested in this answer?